# LWJGL Could Not Compile Shaders

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, shader, lwjgl

I am trying to load a VBO with projection by following the "The Quad with Projection" tutorial on the LWJGL website.

Here is my function for loading the shaders.

```
private int loadShader(String filename, int type) {
    StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    int shaderID = 0;

    try {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                shaderSource.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not read file.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    shaderID = GL20.glCreateShader(type);
    GL20.glShaderSource(shaderID, shaderSource);
    GL20.glCompileShader(shaderID);

    if (GL20.glGetShader(shaderID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("Could not compile shader.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    this.exitOnGLError("loadShader");

    return shaderID;
}
```

When I run the program, this error occurs.

```
if (GL20.glGetShader(shaderID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
    System.err.println("Could not compile shader.");
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

Here is my shader code:

Vertex:

```
#version 150 core

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;

in vec4 in_Position;
in vec4 in_Color;
in vec2 in_TextureCoord;

out vec4 pass_Color;
out vec2 pass_TextureCoord;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = in_Position;
    // Override gl_Position with our new calculated position
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * in_Position;

    pass_Color = in_Color;
    pass_TextureCoord = in_TextureCoord;
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 150 core

uniform sampler2D texture_diffuse;

in vec4 pass_Color;
in vec2 pass_TextureCoord;

out vec4 out_Color;

void main(void) {
    out_Color = pass_Color;
    // Override out_Color with our texture pixel
    out_Color = texture2D(texture_diffuse, pass_TextureCoord);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, if a shader doesn't compile, you should check the shader compilation log. Also, you should post the shader code.

Comment: How would I get the shader compilation log?

Comment: Use [`glGetShaderInfoLog()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetShaderInfoLog.xhtml) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fragment shader is not valid, the function `texture2D` is not available in GLSL 1.50 core. Just use the function [`texture()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/texture.xhtml). The compiler derives the type of the texture to sample from the type of sampler uniform it is called with.